# SQL Query with parameter taking time

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @Id varchar(9)
set @Id='1'
select *  from vw_testview where id=@Id
```

The above query is called in a procedure and is taking about 4 seconds to execute, where as the following query when run individually executes in 0 seconds

```
select * from vw_testview 
where id='1'
```

Could some one please me help with this, i need to decrease the execution time for the first query

Comment: Why are you passing a string value to your int field `id`?

Comment: The Id is a varchar field in the Database, we have values such as 'achd214' in the db. I apologize i had meant to write it as '1a'

Comment: Could you provide us some sample data that includes those string ids?

Comment: Try to use index hint to force sql server to use certain index.

Comment: The Id is always a alphanumeric field with a length of 8. Some examples are 72DA7YEF,12j4hjng

Answer (score 2):

When SQL Server builds the query plan it uses the values of parameters and literals to figure out how many rows will be returned. If you use a value that has many rows you could end up with a scan of the entire table and then filter out the rows you need. If you use a value SQL Server knows are rare SQL Server can take a different strategy and use multiple seeks to get the same job done.

In your slow query you are using a local variable and SQL Server will not sniff the value of local variables when it creates the query plan but will use the average density to calculate the estimated number of rows returned.

It looks like you are querying a view here so it is hard to give any advice without seeing the table structures and indexes for all the tables involved and also the query plans you get when you use a literal value and when you use a local variable.

Comment: Good explanation...  questioner can check the following or another link like it to check how to deal with parameter sniffing when it unexpectedly becomes a performance issue http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3257/different-approaches-to-correct-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Thank you Mikael!! for the detailed explanation. I am trying to post the execution plan here, but not sure how to post it, as the execution plan is huge. I apologize i am a fresher here.

Thank you kevin for the reply, i had already tried all the available options for parameter sniffing, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

In you first query, SQL Server is implicitly converting `varchar` to `int` while implementing a table scan. That causes performance issues. Consider defining `@Id` as `int`

Comment: The Id is a varchar field in the Database, we have values such as 'achd214' in the db. I apologize i had meant to write it as '1a'

Comment: If so, then modify your second query to `where id='1'` and check how it performs.

Comment: I modified it the second query, it always executes in 0 seconds.